# glowing object tin three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create a textGeometry in three.js and for some reason it just isn't showing. Also i have looked at other three.js text examples and they just don't show after i use the same method. My code is below thanks.`

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();

loader.load( 'fonts/helvetiker_bold.typeface.json', function ( font ) {

var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( "My Text", {

    font: font,

    size: 50,
    height: 50,
    curveSegments: 12,

    bevelThickness: 2,
    bevelSize: 5,
    bevelEnabled: true

} );

textGeo.computerBoundingBox();

var centerOffset = -0.5 *(textGeo.boundingBox.max.x - textGeo.boundingBox.min.x)
var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, textMaterial );
mesh.position.set( centerOffset, 400, 0 );

var group = new THREE.Group();
group.add(mesh);

scene.add( group );
```

I do have ambient light for the whole scene. Other geometries are showing. Also textgeometry examples on the three.js websited don't work when I take the code and try using it.

Comment: Is there any light source in the scene? As you use `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial()`, which is affected by light.

Comment: Yes, I do have ambient light for the whole scene. Other geometries are showing. Also textgeometry examples on the three.js websited don't work when I take the code and try using it.

Comment: Any error message in the browser console? Is your object in the view of camera? Coulf you make a code snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, I have even pushed the camera a little bit backwards. This is a link to my jsfiddle, I don't know why it isn't running in js fiddle but the code works in my normal browser. https://jsfiddle.net/fm8y33t0/

Comment: Just realised I'm getting this error: THREE.TextGeometry: font parameter is not an instance of THREE.Font.

Comment: Don't worry guys.i got it to work. Forgot to download my font JSON file